# Insert a logo from a folder into excel

Tags: image, vba, excel

I am looking for a way to insert a picture from a folder into a specific cell in excel. The folder contains hundreds of pictures. I am not familiar with excel macros or VBA. The way the code should work is I type the picture name into a cell and the result should extract a picture with the same name from that folder and place it into another cell. The picture being inserted should also be resized. If someone could please give me some guidance as to how this could be done. Thanks. I am sorry for my poor English as it is my second language.

Comment: If you are not familiar with VBA I would suggest getting familiar. Read up on the basics first, then google the different bits of your plan, http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/excel-vba-insert-multiple-images-from-a-folder-to-excel-cells/ to get images from a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are typing your image name as "myImage.jpg" into cell A1 of your worksheet. Make sure it is the full name with the extension. Place this into your worksheet code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim imagePath, fullImagePath, newImageLoc As String

    imagePath = "C:\YourFileLocationPath\" 'set this to where your images are located.
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'Assumming the cell you are entering your image is in A1 or change to whatever cell you want entering in.
        fullImagePath = imagePath & Target.Value
        newImageLoc = Target.Offset(, 2).Address ' this moves the new image location to the cell you enter your image name two columns to the right.
        'Adjusts image size, change as needed
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fullImagePath)
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 100
            End With
            .Left = ActiveSheet.Range(newImageLoc).Left
            .Top = ActiveSheet.Range(newImageLoc).Top
            .Placement = 1
            .PrintObject = True
        End With
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, we ran into a problem where by the picture is moved by the length of the cell. Is there a way we could have the picture move through a different measurement system in excel? For example by inches?

Comment: what do you mean? the picture is resized when the cell is resized?

Comment: The dilemma is that my excel template has various sized cells and we are trying to place the picture in a specific location but are having a hard time. This is because the current code moves the picture by cells so if the cell is too long, the picture will move the whole length of the cell. I was wondering if this could be changed such that the image can be placed directly at a certain point and not designated by cells.

Comment: might want to ask a new question then.

Comment: Thanks for your help!